# Confused on marking figured bass for modulating sequence

Tags: harmony, chord-theory, figured-bass

I started writing down the figured bass of an anime theme, and for a particular passage, I am confused on how to accurately write the figured bass progression. I have recreated the bare progressions excerpt below:

[image: chordal analysis of theme]
From what I have learned after pouring through the Internet and my old Harmony and voice leading textbook, I believe from measure (mm) 4, the key goes from g minor to the eventual D Major through the III7 as a altered common chord (with the C#). What follows in mm 5-7 is a descending sequence of 5ths that eventually ends in the D Major.

Is my analysis correct? And if so, how should I best write out the figured bass accurately?

Answer (score 3):

Your chord analysis is good. Here's my version, which is fundamentally the same. The common chord you refer to is an [applied dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_chord#Secondary_dominant), labeled V/v (read: "five of (minor) five")

```
X: 1
T: Anime Theme Analysis
M: 4/4
L: 1/4
K: Gmin
V:RH
V:LH clef=bass
[V:RH]"g min:" y [B,E]4 | [CF]4 | [B,E]4 | [A,D]4 | [^C=E]4 | [FA]2 [DB]2 | [EC']2 [^C']2 | [D']4
[V:LH] y [C,G,C]4 | [D,D]2 D,/2C,/2A,,/2C,/2 | [C,G,C]4 | [B,,B,]4 | [A,,A,]4 | [D,A,]2 [G,,D,G,]2 | [C,C]2 [A,,^C]2 | [D,A,]4
s: iv7 | v7 | iv7 | III7 | V/v | v i | iv V/v | v
```

Just know, this is a [Roman numeral analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis), not [figured bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figured_bass). Figured bass includes only the intervals above the bass and is not explicit about the name or function of the chord.